# Child process (using python multiprocessing) hangs when using sklearn LinearRegression fit method

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing

Each of the processes I'm trying to run must, among other tasks, fit linear regressions. However, as soon as the corresponding fit method (sklearn's linear regression) is called under a child process, it hangs. Running a decision tree regressor does not result in the same problem.

Python version is 3.7.5

Numpy version is 1.17.4

Sklearn version is 0.23.1

Minimum reproducible example below :

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing as mp
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor

def exp(X,y):
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(X,y)
    print('fitted')

    def job(X,y):
        #model = DecisionTreeRegressor() #(works...)
        model = LinearRegression() # (hangs...)
        model.fit(X,y)
        print('fitted (child process)')


    p = mp.Process(target = job, args=(X,y))
    p.start()
    p.join()
    print('done')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    n_obs = 100
    X = np.random.random((n_obs,1))
    y = np.random.random((n_obs))
    exp(X,y)
```

```
fitted
```

Comment: Is this really your actual code? `p = mp.Process(target = job, args=())` and the next 3 lines must be enclosed within a block governed by `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Comment: The minimum reproducible example was written and run in a notebook, hence the absence of the "__main__" block. However, the actual code is run as a regular python script. I updated the example in the original comment to make it a .py executable.

Comment: It runs as expected when the DecisionTreeRegressor is used.

Comment: Your function accesses variables outside of it's scope. Can you pass X,Y to the function? Many problems in Python are just scope problems under the hood

Comment: Scope was correct. Otherwise the DecisionTreeRegressor would not work properly either. I updated the code nonetheless and the result is the same.

Comment: The code did not run for me because `job` was defined inside of `exp`. Moving it to the outer scope solved the problem and the code ran to completion with both `DecisionTreeRegressor` and `LinearRegression`. I have a guess though: try including `n_jobs=1` in `LinearRegression`. Does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I get the same result specifying n_jobs = 1 with LinearRegression